# Ambiguous definition of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Looking at a set defined as:

$$S= \bigg\{\frac{a}{b} \bigg| a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b \;\text{odd}\bigg\}$$

I am puzzled by the fact that if:

$$x= \frac23, y = \frac46$$

then $x=y$ but $x\in S$ while $y\not \in S$.

How is it concealable?

Comment: I'm guessing that the author forgot to mention that $a/b$ is in lowest terms, i.e. that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example $y$ **is** an element of $S$: as you say, $y=x$, and $x\in S$. The particular **name** $\frac46$ doesn’t immediately show that the number is in $S$, but the number itself is, because it’s the same number as $\frac23$.

Comment: Okay, nice perspective, indeed there is a non unique relationship between the quantity and its representation. Many thanks.

Comment: I would say that unless you specifically resolve fractional representations into equivalence classes (by equality in their simplest form) then both 2/3 and 4/6 are in S. Yes, no ?

Comment: @Tom: No, because *both* implies that they are different things. In the context that we’ve been given this is not the case: so far as we can tell, $\frac{a}b$ is simply a rational number, not a specific ordered pair of integers.